# Does HR of my company have an obligation to provide related documents

Tags: human-resources, legal, australia, documentation

Just wanted to know, if an HR department has an obligation towards employees.

Let's say I need a document of employment generated by HR, needed by a service provider. I am following up with HR for weeks and the HR manager will not respond.

Yes, this triggered me to leave the job and will act on that, but what are my options?

I could understand if they are busy and could have easily mentioned that.

This is so frustrating.

I am currently in Melbourne, Australia.

Comment: It might depend on the specific document. This almost certainly varies by location, so it'd help if you could include country (or even state if in the US). Is this a document that belongs to you that they won't return or is this something that was generated by the company that you just need access to?

Comment: @Simsons, Do you mean to say you ask HR to provide you with the proof of your current employment at the company (so that you can show it to a third party) ? and HR does not respond ?

Comment: @BSMP, I am in Melbourne, Australia . I need a document generated by HR. Edited the question. Thanks .

Comment: @Job_September_2020, yes. I need a prrod of employement which is needed by a service provider and HR wont respond.

Comment: By "service provider", do you mean an "employment service provider" that you're obligated to work with in order to receive Centrelink payments? If you're on the JobSeeker allowance, you're not allowed to quit your job, and Centrelink will cut your payments if you do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of document certainly matters.

If it is proof of employment document, [you have a right, under Australian law](https://www.fairwork.gov.au/tools-and-resources/fact-sheets/rights-and-obligations/record-keeping-pay-slips#What-are-the-record-keeping-obligations), to have access to those documents.

If they are not responding to emails, you should pick up the phone and call them.

If they are actively avoiding you, your next step would be to get in touch with [Fairwork Australia](https://www.fairwork.gov.au/contact-us).

Answer (score 3):

Switch from email to daily phone calls to hourly phone calls to 10 minute calls to calls every minute. You will get your paperwork when creating your paperwork is less inconvenience than getting your calls.

They are inconveniencing you, you should inconvenience them.